# Total count with all parent and child in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

**tbl_cat:**

```
id parent_id cat_name 
1   0           a
2   1           b
3   1           c
4   0           d
5   4           f
```

**tbl_article:**

```
id cat_id article
1    1      abc
2    1      xyz
3    2      hgu
4    4      hju
5    3      kkk
```

I want to count how many article of parent with all child. I want record like

```
  id parent_id cat_name article_count
    1   0           a          3
    2   1           b          NULL
    3   1           c          NULL
    4   0           d          1
    5   4           f          NULL
```

Comment: Don't understand the record you are trying to get. shouldn't the article count for cat_id 1 be 2 instead of 3 ? Because I only see 2 articles having cat_id 1, Also 2 and 3 should be one each no?

Comment: I think what he means is that he wants the aggregated result. So for one cat he wants all children. but not the parent.

Comment: @helgeheldre, that still doesn't give the example result he required. Regardless, if someone asks a question where there is no clear link between the source data and what is required and the OP doesn't even bother to stick around to give more details, it's just wasting a potential answerer's time.

Comment: @AshwinNair I agree, he could be more specific in describing the result. Especially since like you pointed out it does not seem correct in relation to the data he has provided. 
I was doing a best guess, thats why its a comment and not in an answer with SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT()` to count the number of rows and you can use `JOIN` to match the articles with their categories based on `cat_id`. You will have 0 instead of `NULL` though because that's the way `COUNT()` counts rows, if there are no rows it will return 0, not `NULL`.

```
SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.cat_name, COUNT(*) AS article_count
FROM tbl_cat AS c JOIN tbl_article AS a ON c.id=a.cat_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
SELECT c.id,c.parent_id,c.cat_name,a.article_count    
FROM tbl_cat AS c 
,(
  SELECT cat_id,COUNT(article) AS article_count
  FROM tbl_article
  GROUP BY cat_id
 ) AS a
WHERE c.id = a.cat_id
```

Comment: This won't give the expected answer either. It'll return article_count as {2,1,1,1,0} what he actually wants even if i consider nulls as 0s {3,0,0,1,0} .i think the question is flawed.